# SQL Server full text is not working if there is one word in the column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition.

I applied full text for a column. I am getting all results having character 'AB' in LIKE clause, but it's not working if I give same 'AB' for contains.

```
SELECT * 
FROM metal_master
WHERE CONTAINS (description, ' "*ab*" ') 


SELECT * 
FROM metal_master
WHERE description LIKE '%AB%'
```

In first case, I got 1378 records, the second case, I got 15,945 records.

When I checked, all the result of 'contains' have more than 1 word. It's not considering if 1 word is there, which `LIKE` is considering.

Comment: The SQL Server fulltext searching is **word-based** - i.e. it works against words and word stems - but just single characters.

Comment: 1. Does that mean what I am expecting is not possible? But, I have seen "*some_char*" returns record even if it is a substring which is why I used ' * ' on both sides. Sorry, but I didn't understand your comment. Can you write little more as I am new to this FullText